# How to merge days with similar start and end hours using Salesforce Apex?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience

I'm trying to write an Apex method to merge days with similar start and end hours together. For example, the data looks like

Hours:{Name=ConsultantHours, SundayStartTime=00:00:00.000Z, SundayEndTime=00:00:00.000Z, MondayStartTime=08:00:00.000Z, MondayEndTime=18:00:00.000Z, TuesdayStartTime=07:00:00.000Z, TuesdayEndTime=19:00:00.000Z, WednesdayStartTime=08:00:00.000Z, WednesdayEndTime=18:00:00.000Z, ThursdayStartTime=09:00:00.000Z, ThursdayEndTime=20:00:00.000Z, FridayStartTime=07:00:00.000Z, FridayEndTime=19:00:00.000Z, SaturdayStartTime=00:00:00.000Z, SaturdayEndTime=00:00:00.000Z, TimeZoneSidKey=America/Los_Angeles}

I have to use all the above data except Name and Timezone and merge days based on Start and End time. we have to simplify like

**Monday & Wednesday : 8:00 a.m. to 6:00 p.m 
Tuesday & Friday : 7:00 a.m. to 7:00 p.m 
Thursday : 9:00 a.m. to 8:00 p.m 
Saturday & Sunday : Holiday**

And, if the data is

Hours:{Id=01mS0000000CeCVIA0, Name=ConsultantHours, SundayStartTime=00:00:00.000Z, SundayEndTime=00:00:00.000Z, MondayStartTime=08:00:00.000Z, MondayEndTime=18:00:00.000Z, TuesdayStartTime=08:00:00.000Z, TuesdayEndTime=18:00:00.000Z, WednesdayStartTime=08:00:00.000Z, WednesdayEndTime=18:00:00.000Z, ThursdayStartTime=09:00:00.000Z, ThursdayEndTime=20:00:00.000Z, FridayStartTime=09:00:00.000Z, FridayEndTime=20:00:00.000Z, SaturdayStartTime=09:00:00.000Z, SaturdayEndTime=20:00:00.000Z, TimeZoneSidKey=America/Los_Angeles}

We have to simplify like

**Monday- Wednesday : 8:00 a.m. to 6:00 p.m 
Thursday - Saturday : 9:00 a.m. to 8:00 p.m 
Sunday : Holiday**

Is there a way of accomplishing this using Apex coding ?

The Query I used to fetch the above data is :

**List hrLst = [SELECT Id, Name, SundayStartTime, SundayEndTime, MondayStartTime, MondayEndTime, TuesdayStartTime, TuesdayEndTime, WednesdayStartTime, WednesdayEndTime, ThursdayStartTime, ThursdayEndTime, FridayStartTime, FridayEndTime, SaturdayStartTime, SaturdayEndTime, TimeZoneSidKey FROM Hours WHERE Name = 'ConsultantHours' AND IsActive = TRUE];**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of apex collection data types, a set of string to hold the days of the week, a Map of List data type to group the days by the start-end time.

```java
Set<String> days = new Set<String>{'Monday', ..., 'Sunday'};
Map<String, List<String>> daysByTime = new Map<String, List<String>>();
// assuming hour is your Hours sobject
for (String day : days) {
   String key = hour.get(day + 'StartTime') + hour.get(day + 'EndTime');
   if (!daysByTime.containsKey(key)) {
       daysByTime.put(key, new List<String>>());
   }
   daysByTime.get(key).add(day);
}
// print out by looping thru the map keys
for (String key : daysByTime.keySet()) {
   // get the first index of list using .get(0)
   // get the last index of list .get(list size()-1)
}
```

You need to perform a bit of formatting on the date to display them as what you wanted.
Check out the DateTime [apex class reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm).